# Not able to run as JBPM project in Eclipse 2018-12 and JBPM7.15

Tags: project, jbpm

I am looking to run a sample JBPM Project as JBPM project with the run time config. I have the bpmn modeler and jbpm plugin installed from market place. But when i see the Run as config I am not getting the jbpm configuration? How do i run it as jbpm project? is there

I tried to compile as Maven project and it compiles just fine but wont run as a JBPM project

I need the sample JBPM project to run as JBPM service so i can trigger new instance of that process and access the status of that work item etc.,

Comment: thanks. It solved my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special jBPM run configuration available in eclipse.

You have two options 
1) Run as JUnit test case or

[JUnit Example](https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-examples/src/test/java/org/jbpm/examples/quickstarts/JavaServiceQuickstartTest.java)

2) Run as Java Application

[Java App Example](https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-examples/src/main/java/org/jbpm/examples/request/ProcessTest.java)